# Encrypt all data from Python script to a Server

Tags: python-3.x, encryption

I am looking for a way to secure the data being sent from my Python script to my server via a known network.

Python Script - > Known Network -> Server

I want the known network so i can restrict all other hosts from accessing the server and only allow the known network to access it.

The Server is running MariaDB, Apache2, SSH and other default Debian packages. My Python script will be run on a number of windows 7 and windows 10 computers.

I only want the connection from the script to be run through this system and all other applications to just use the normal internet.

I am looking into SSH Tunnels, VPNs and SOCKS5 proxy but im not sure which one i need. I have no restriction on speed so if the encryption method takes a second or two to complete i am happy with that.

Can anyone provide any guidance as to how i can achieve this and which protocol i would need ?